# How can I change my login name?

Tags: login, users

I don't mean the first encrypt password, but that login name that appears in **logout from user** mode, **change user**, etc. The second password where I wrote my real name.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate and most users don't log in using text mode. They want to change the full name that shows in the GUI login screen, which is not the username.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I agree with you and I voted to leave open and then reopen, but could you edit the question at all to improve it? I edited to correct obvious problems but I still find it quite unclear...

Answer (score 0):

I found it under **Settings** and inside **About me** so it's easy after all.